# How does modulus?

Tags: modulo

I'm extremely new to software engineering and I don't fully understand how modulus.  I understand it with simple numbers but one example I don't understand is how (0-1) % 60 equals 59.  Hoping someone doesn't mind answering this very much beginner's question.

Answer (score 0):

Think about modulo as dividing the first number by the second number and then taking the remainder.
For instance 10 % 2 is 0 because 10 is 10 / 2 = 5 R 0.
Also 5 % 4 = 1 because 5 / 4 = 1 R 1.

Then to go to your example:
-1 % 60 = -1 R 59
This is because a remainder always has to be positive and -1 * 60 + 59 = -1

Comment: So in my example -1 / 60 = -0.01666666666. I'm not understanding how 59 is the remainder. I understand remainders when the first number is larger than the second but not vice versa.

Comment: If we think about it from backwards standpoint it might be easier.

Using a simple example we have something like:  

50/ 60 = 0 R 50         We get this from the fact that 60 * 0 + 50 = 50  

Moving onto your example:  

-1 / 60 = -1 R 59 because -1 * 60 + 59  = 59.

Comment: So would the formula to solve  x % y  be  x / y = z (rounded down)  and to solve for R  it would be  x - y * z = R  ?